# Impersonate User for Entity Connection WPF Desktop

Tags: entity-framework, impersonation

Problem :

SQ Server setup with permissions for one generic Windows Account.

Client :

WPF Application using EntityFramework.

Similar to these:

[LogonUserEx, DuplicateTokenEx for Impersonation with an ObjectContext in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008049/logonuserex-duplicatetokenex-for-impersonation-with-an-objectcontext-in-c-sharp)

[Impersonation failing for database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961496/impersonation-failing-for-database-connection)

There was no clear solution in these.  After trying out lot of different options and failing, I went to basics.

Created  a Console App using the MSDN example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx

Also, tried the Simple Impersonation

[How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net/7250145)

However, I keep getting System.StackOverflowException was unhandled  exception
{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}

after this line:

```
 bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, Console.ReadLine(),
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                out safeTokenHandle);

            Console.WriteLine("LogonUser called.");
```

When I experimented with the LOGON_TYPE

```
using (SimpleImpersonation.Impersonation.LogonUser("domain", "user", "password", SimpleImpersonation.LogonType.Network))
{
   Console.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

        }
```

LogonType.Network is the only one which does not give exception.
And it displays the new user name.

However, when I try:

```
using (SimpleImpersonation.Impersonation.LogonUser("domain", "user", "password", SimpleImpersonation.LogonType.Network))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);  // works as expected , correct user name
            try
            {
                model.MyEntities te = new MyEntities();
                model.PMGroup p = te.PMGroups.Where(g => g.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message  + Environment.NewLine  + e.InnerException.Message);
            }

        }
```

I get this : 
The underlying provider failed on Open.

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

I would this to connect as the new user not anon.

Update:

**Impersonation works if the Project Target is .Net3.5 or below. 
It does not work for .Net 4 and .Net 4.5**

Maybe I am approaching this problem all wrong.  If you have any ideas or suggestions, please share.

Thanks